# Cómo agregar dos clases en un observable collection?

Tags: c#, observable, basic

Tengo la clase pelicula y la clase serie. Las cuales quiero agregar a un observable collection para después visualizar los valores de año y titulo en un listview. 
Recién estoy aprendiendo así que no sé mucho en realidad... antes solo había hecho cosas como esta:

```cs
  ObservableCollection<Alumno> alumnos = new ObservableCollection<Alumno>();
```

Ahí estoy utilizando una clase, pero ahora necesito usar dos. 
De qué manera podría hacerlo?

Comment: No acabo de entender tu pregunta ¿Podrías añadir más detalles? Algo más de código y contexto sería de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema puede resolverse usando [herencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance), es decir, definiendo un tipo base con los miembros comunes (fecha y título en ese caso) y dos tipos que deriven de ese tipo base añadiendo cualesquiera otros miembros que sean necesarios.

Una manera de hacer eso es usar un tipo abstracto:

```
abstract class ObraAudiovisual
{
    public DateTime Fecha {get; protected set;}
    public string Titulo {get; protected set;}
}

class Pelicula : ObraAudiovisual
{
    public Pelicula(DateTime fecha, string Titulo)
    {
        this.Fecha = fecha;
        this.Titulo = Titulo;
    }
}

class Serie : ObraAudiovisual
{
    //Constructor como en Pelicula
}
```

En este ejemplo he definido las propiedades `Fecha` y `Titulo` como de "sólo lectura" (se establecen en el constructor y no pueden modificarse externamente), pero tienes más posibilidades; puedes por ejemplo definirlas como de lectura y escritura públicas (`{get; set;}`) y ahorrarte el constructor.

La otra posibilidad es usar un interfaz como tipo base:

```
interface ObraAudiovisual
{
    DateTime Fecha { get; }
    string Titulo { get; }
}

class Pelicula : ObraAudiovisual
{
    public DateTime Fecha { get; protected set; }
    public string Titulo { get; protected set; }

    public Pelicula(DateTime fecha, string Titulo)
    {
        this.Fecha = fecha;
        this.Titulo = Titulo;
    }
}

class Serie : ObraAudiovisual
{
    //Definición de propiedades y constructor como en Pelicula
}
```

En general, si tienes funcionalidad común más allá de unas pocas propiedades (p. ej. métodos) la clase abstracta es más conveniente ya que evitas duplicación de código.

Una vez tienes definidos tus tipos, puedes crear tu colección así:

```
var series = new ObservableCollection<ObraAudiovisual>();
```

...y podrás insertar en ella instancias tanto de película como de serie. Si necesitas saber el tipo concreto de un objeto, puedes usar [el operador is](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) (`if(instancia is Pelicula) {...}`) o [typeof](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) (`if(instancia.GetType() == typeof(Pelicula)) {...}`).